# AngularJS template vs templateURL in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive defined like this:

```
app.directive('itemComments', ['ajax', function(ajax) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: URL + 'public/Pages/Homepage/ajax/getCommentsTpl',
            controller: 'ItemLibraryController',
            controllerAs: 'itemLibraryCtrl',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                var $element = $(element);
                scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                    return $element.find('li').length > 0;
                }, function(finished) {
                    if(finished) {
                        autosize($element.find('textarea'));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The template specified by `"templateUrl"` returns something like this:

```
...
<textarea class="form-control textarea-resize" ng-keyup="commentPost($event)" ng-model="textComment"></textarea>
...
```

In ItemLibraryController I have defined the method commentPost() that is accessed on keyup on textarea.
The problem is that `$scope.textComment = undefined` instead of the value entered in textarea. If i modify in html `ng-model="$parent.textComment"` then the value from the textarea is found in `$scope.textComment`.

PS. When using "template" instead of "templateUrl" in the directive definition, the ng-model problem disappears.

**My questions are:**

1. Why do i have to use $parent.textComment since the scope of the template is the ItemLibraryController?
2. Why using templateUrl creates another scope for the ng-models inside the template?
3. Why, when using "template" instead of "templateUrl" in directive definition, the ng-model problem disappears?
4. How can i access textComment without using $parent.textComment?

Comment: how you defined the value of `textComment` in parent scope, using `$scope.textComment` or `this.textComment`?

Comment: i use $scope.textComment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem to solve this issue would be using dot rule of AngularJS`, so that the object will for [**prototypal inheritance**][1]. For that you need to create and object and add the`textComment`in it, so the object will look like`$scope.library={}`then`textComment`will be placed in it. Also you need to make add`scope: true` to say that directive will follow inheritance of an object.

**Template**

```
...
<textarea class="form-control textarea-resize" 
   ng-keyup="commentPost($event)" 
   ng-model="library.textComment">
</textarea>
...
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('itemComments', ['ajax', function(ajax) {
    return {
        scope: true, //<--added here
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: URL + 'public/Pages/Homepage/ajax/getCommentsTpl',
        controller: 'ItemLibraryController',
        controllerAs: 'itemLibraryCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            //code here
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Hmmm.. i've created a local object like scope.library = {textComment: ''} in the "link" method of the directive and then i used ng-model="library.textComment" and it worked without using "scope: true" in the directive. So i'll mark this answer as accepted since it pushed me down the right path.